# tortoisegit No supported authentication methods available when pushing (not pulling)

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Git is working fine from the command line

When I tell tortoise to push though, I get the above error.

I don't really know what I'm doing, but I tried using puttygen to create a key, pasted it into github, and added it to pageant. However it still produces the same error.

Any solutions for this?

Edit: I seem to have gotten it to work by changing the endpoint to `https://myusername@github.com/ProjectName/Project.git` which prompted me for a password instead. This hasn't exactly solved the mystery of the keys but it works and my experience is that you should be blessed if you get git to do anything remotely close to what you want.

Comment: Using latest TortoiseGit?

Comment: Yes, latest version of tortoisegit. I'm happy to forget about it if the solution isn't obvious although typing my password every time I push using it is a pain

Comment: problem with SSH. search the issue tracker. http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/issues/detail?id=1880

Comment: Came across this too. To solve the password issue either install the Git Credential WinStore helper which will store the password for you saving it to be re-entered a number of times: http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/ or use basic HTTP authentication (i.e http://myusername:mypassword@github.com)